# How to find out if an Oracle column is SecureFile

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle 11gR2 which view(s) I have to query to find out if a CLOB column is stored as SecureFile?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the dba_lobs view (or all_lobs/user_lobs if you don't have the necessary privileges):

```
select * from dba_lobs where securefile = 'YES'
```